# Spark in Yarn Web UI not getting displayed

Tags: apache-spark

I am unable to view Spark history through Yarn UI(yarn web address 8088 in yarn-site.ml). Spark job completed successfully
Spark application was run in datanode shell with cluster-mode as cluster

When clicked on history it is redirecting to http://namenode:18088/history/application_1472647811761_0001/1 and it says page cannot be displayed

Hadoop Version: 2.7.0
Spark Version:  2.0.0
Cluster: one namenode and one datanode

```
   spark-default.xml
   spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://namenode:9000/user/spark/applicationHistory
   spark.eventLog.enabled=true
   spark.yarn.historyServer.address=namenode:18088
   spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://namenode:9000/shared/spark-logs
```

Comment: Is the namenode property value of 18088 a mismatch to 8088? The latter is cited in your prose as being in yarn-site.ml, but the former is in your code format block

Comment: These are two different properties yarn web address is configured in yarn-site.xml where as the other one is in spark-default.xml .Spark documentation doesn't mention that these 2 have to be same

Comment: Why do you specify `spark.yarn.historyServer.address`? Do you have History Server up and running?

Comment: spark history server is running, the "page cannot be displayed " issue got resolved by changing the port to 18080 in spark.yarn.historyServer.address=namenode:18080, but now the issue is spark history webpage is saying application [application id] not found?what could be wrong here

Comment: It is resolved now changed the property in spark-default.conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://namenode:9000/shared/spark-log to hdfs://namenode:9000/user/spark/applicationHistory i.e it is now same as spark.eventLog.dir